# Swift: Storing Array of Optionals to NSUserDefaults?

Tags: arrays, swift, nsuserdefaults

I am trying to save an array of optionals `Strings` to `NSUserDefaults`, but unfortunately it doesn't work:

```
var textFieldEntries: [String?]
...
func encodeWithCoder(aCoder: NSCoder!) {
    aCoder.encodeObject(textFieldEntries, forKey: "textFieldEntries")
    // prints error: Cannot convert value of type '[String?]'
    // to expected argument type 'AnyObject?'
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`[String?]` is a Swift type that cannot be represented as a Foundation type. Normally, Swift Array bridges to `NSArray`, but an `NSArray` cannot contain nil. An Array of Optionals can contain nil, so it doesn't bridge automatically.

You could work around this by using a sparse array representation. (And since your content is strings — a property list type and therefore legal for use in `NSUserDefaults` — you don't even need to use `NSCoding` to encode the array.) A dictionary makes a pretty good sparse array:

```
var textFieldEntries: [String?] = ["foo", nil, "bar"]

func saveToDefaults() {
    var sparseArray: [String: String] = [:] // plists need string keys
    for (index, entry) in textFieldEntries.enumerate() {
        if let e = entry {
            sparseArray["\(index)"] = e
        }
    }
    // sparseArray = ["0": "foo", "2": "bar"]

    let defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
    defaults.setObject(sparseArray, forKey: "textFieldEntries")
}
```

Then, when you go to read in your data from defaults, convert from the sparse-array dictionary form to the array-of-optionals form. That's a little bit more fun because you need to figure out from the sparse representation how many nils you need the array to store.

```
func readFromDefaults() {
    let defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
    guard let sparseArray = defaults.objectForKey("textFieldEntries") as? [String: String]
        else { fatalError("unepxected defaults key format") }

    // count of the sparse array = index of highest key + 1
    let count = sparseArray.keys.flatMap({Int($0)}).maxElement()! + 1

    // wipe the old array to put nils in all the right places
    textFieldEntries = [String?](count: count, repeatedValue: nil)

    // fill in the values
    for (strindex, entry) in sparseArray {
        guard let index = Int(strindex)
            else { fatalError("non-numeric key") }

        textFieldEntries[index] = entry
    }
}
```

(Alternately, you might know that `count` is constant because it's, say, the number of text fields in your UI.)

Answer (score 0):

Let's say this is the original array

```
let textFieldEntries: [String?]
```

First of all let's turn the array of `String?` into an array of `String`.

```
let entries = textFieldEntries.flatMap { $0 }
```

Now we can save it

```
NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(entries, forKey: "entries")
```

And retrieve it

```
if let retrieved = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("entries") as? [String] {
    // here your have your array
    print(retrieved)
}
```

Comment: But then what do you do on restoring state from defaults? Now that you've `flatMap`ped the array, you don't know which indices had nils. Presumably the reason the OP is using `[String?]` in the first place is that some indices can be empty.

Comment: @rickster: Good point! If the OP does need to save the `nil` values as well I can think to a more detailed solution.

Comment: [Here's one solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34053503/957768), though it's far from the only possible one.